Lazy evaluation in Rust
I am a Rust noob with extensive Java experience.
There is code that runs through some logic and eventually comes up with the status of those calculations, captured in Report (see below). The Report is only used under certain circumstances, so I don't need its contents (just a String) to be evaluated if it is not necessary, so I use LazyCell.
use std::cell::LazyCell;
use std::error::Error;
use std::fmt;
use std::fmt::Display;
use std::fmt::Formatter;

pub struct Report {
    msg: LazyCell<String>,
}

impl Report {
    pub fn from_err(err: impl Display) -> Self {
        Report { msg: LazyCell::new(|| { err.to_string() }) }
    }
    pub fn from_str(str: String) -> Self {
        Report { msg: LazyCell::new(|| { str }) }
    }
}

impl Display for Report {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "SimpleError: {}", *self.msg)
    }
}

Obviously it doesn't compile complaining "closures can only be coerced to `fn` types if they do not capture any variables". My intent is to simply keep err and only extract its string form if/when needed.
I suspect I'm not approaching it "the Rust way" in which case I need to get out of my boxed vision of this, but my Rust field of view is still limited

You can do it with OnceCell, which is powering LazyCell:
use std::cell::OnceCell;
use std::fmt;
use std::fmt::Display;
use std::fmt::Formatter;

pub struct Report<T> {
    disp: Option<T>,
    msg: OnceCell<String>,
}

impl<T: Display> Report<T> {
    pub fn from_err(disp: T) -> Self {
        Report {
            disp: Some(disp),
            msg: OnceCell::new(),
        }
    }
    fn msg(&self) -> &str {
        self.msg.get_or_init(|| {
            self.disp
                .as_ref()
                .expect("if `msg` is not initialized `disp` can only be `Some`")
                .to_string()
        })
    }
    pub fn from_str(str: String) -> Self {
        Report {
            disp: None,
            msg: OnceCell::from(str),
        }
    }
}

impl<T: Display> Display for Report<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "SimpleError: {}", self.msg())
    }
}

You can avoid the generic parameter if you use Box<dyn Display>.
Also note that if you always have mutable access to the cell (not true in this case because of Display taking &self) you can use Option with get_or_insert_with(), which is just a bit faster than OnceCell (it doesn't need to protect from recursive initialization).

LazyCell actually takes two generic parameters: the first is of course the type of the data, but the second is the type of the callback. It is defaulted to fn() -> Data to assist with the common case (especially with LazyLock) of lazily-initializing a static, but in your case you can specify it as Box<dyn FnOnce() -> String>:
use std::cell::LazyCell;
use std::fmt;
use std::fmt::Display;
use std::fmt::Formatter;

pub struct Report {
    msg: LazyCell<String, Box<dyn FnOnce() -> String>>,
}

impl Report {
    pub fn from_err(err: impl Display + 'static) -> Self {
        Report {
            msg: LazyCell::new(Box::new(move || err.to_string())),
        }
    }
    pub fn from_str(str: String) -> Self {
        Report {
            msg: LazyCell::new(Box::new(move || str)),
        }
    }
}

impl Display for Report {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "SimpleError: {}", *self.msg)
    }
}

